# Wireless Drivers for Inspiron 1420 using Unbutu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

Inspiron 1420 wireless config not visible. Need driver & directions to install. Below is screenshot of WiFi board:

Oc:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03) Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1500 Draft 802.11n WLAN Mini-card

Control: 1/0- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTX- Status: Cap+ 66MHZ- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- SERR- <PERR- INTX-

Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17

Region: Memory at fe8fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Region 2: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]

Capabilities:

Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge